# Javascript - URL Detection in other instance of IE Browser window

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code for URL Detection if it is already opened in any of the browser window or tab and i have achieved it so far but failing in one instance i.e., if the url is already opened in other window and then if i launch the application in another window of IE then it should not launch as one instance is already opened and the already opened instance should be set to focus....

please guide me.....

```
var memberURL = document.URL;
var newWindowCopy = document.URL;
var winBrowser = window.clientInformation.appName;
var stringText = window.clientInformation.userAgent.toString();
var localVariable = "IamAliveInLocalStorage";

if (winBrowser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || stringText.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("MyStorage") == localVariable) { 
            open(memberURL, newWindowCopy).close();
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem("MyStorage", localVariable);
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            localStorage.removeItem("MyStorage");
            localStorage.clear();
        };
    }
}
else { }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to focus a window or tab of which you are not having a reference i.e only the child windows your page opens can be focused with `window.focus()` method.

But there is a trick which you can use i.e `alert()` fetches the focus to its window.

So on your page you can add a check

```
function focusOnOpenedTab() {
    var temp = localStorage.getItem('focusOnTab');
    localStorage.setItem('focusOnTab',JSON.stringify(~~temp+1));
}
if(// page is open in any window){
    focusOnOpenedTab()
} else {
    window.addEventListener("storage", message_receive);

    function message_receive(ev) {
        if (ev.key == 'focusOnTab') {
            var message=JSON.parse(ev.newValue);
            alert('focused');
        }
    }
}
```

Your page will get focused and get an `alert` with message `focused`.